# Hive table on HBase table showing NULL for integer columns

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

I am trying to create Hive table over Hbase table. Details shown below:

**HBase table has data like:**

```
Connected to: Phoenix (version 4.7)
Driver: PhoenixEmbeddedDriver (version 4.7)
Autocommit status: true
Transaction isolation: TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
Building list of tables and columns for tab-completion (set fastconnect to true to skip)...
1341/1341 (100%) Done
Done
sqlline version 1.1.8

0: jdbc:phoenix:maxiqtesting1.lti.com:2181:/h> 
select * from HBASE_TEST_6JULY_1792409;

+---------+---------+---------+

| FIELD0  | FIELD1  | FIELD2  |

+---------+---------+---------+

| 1       | qq      | 23      |

| 2       | ee      | 12      |

| 3       | dd      | 123     |

+---------+---------+---------+


3 rows selected (0.139 seconds)
0: jdbc:phoenix:maxiqtesting1.lti.com:2181:/h>
```

**create Hive Table command:**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE HBASE_TEST_6JULY(FIELD0 int,FIELD1 string, FIELD2 int) 
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,0:FIELD1,0:FIELD2","hbase.table.default.storage.type" = "binary",  'serialization.format'='1')
TBLPROPERTIES("hbase.table.name" = "HBASE_TEST_6JULY_1792409");
```

**SELECT command on Hive table gives result as:**

```
hive> select * from HBASE_TEST_6JULY;
OK

-2147483647     qq      -2147483625

-2147483646     ee      -2147483636

-2147483645     dd      -2147483525

Time taken: 0.963 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
```

**The integer columns values are not displayed correctly. If I give all columns as String in hive then I am getting null for corresponding integer columns in HBase**

Can anyone please help me and provide solution to read numeric/non-string columns with correct value by exposing Hive tables on HBase ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To read the non-string columns from hbase, you ddl statement should read

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE HBASE_TEST_6JULY(
FIELD0 int,
FIELD1 string, 
FIELD2 int
) 
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key#b,0:FIELD1,0:FIELD2#b",  'serialization.format'='1')
TBLPROPERTIES("hbase.table.name" = "HBASE_TEST_6JULY_1792409");
```

Note the use of "#b" in the column mapping qualifier for the int columns. 
This fixed it for me.

[See the jira issue thread on this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1634)